# Adding class ids to ExtJS Grid Columns

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I understand you can add **class ids** to ExtJS components using the **addCls** method like so

```
this.myGrid.addCls('MyGrid');
```

can this be added as a constructor property? I want to add class ids to columns, however it would be nice to add this at construction time like so :

```
{
        dataIndex: 'packageName',
        text: 'Name of Packet',
        width: 300,
        filter: {
            type: 'string'
        }
        IsThereSomKindOfAddCLsEquivalent : 'packageName'

}
```

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-cls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please try the below once
 {

```
        text: 'Opportunities',
        dataIndex: 'name_s',
        tdCls: 'allow-wrap',
        renderer: this.ColumnTextRenderer,
        flex: 1,
        maxWidth: 500
    }
```

Hope this helps you.